# How to initialize array elements with their indices

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to find an elegant way of initializing C++ array elements with their indices. I have a lot of code that looks like this:

```
static constexpr size_t ELEMENT_COUNT = 8;
MyObject x[ELEMENT_COUNT] = {{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}};
```

Where `MyObject` is effectively,

```
struct MyObject {
    size_t mMyIndex;
    MyObject(size_t myIndex) : mMyIndex(myIndex) {}
};
```

The problems should be already clear: when `ELEMENT_COUNT` changes, I have to adapt the initializer list, which feels very un-C++. And if `ELEMENT_COUNT` is, say, `1000`, this becomes impractical.

Is something like the following possible in C++?:

```
MyObject mObjects[ELEMENT_COUNT] = initialize_array_with_indices<ELEMENT_COUNT>();
```

Does such a function like `initialize_array_with_indices<N>()` exist in the std library? Is it possible? Using `std::array<>` is an option, if that gets me further.

Comment: I also recommend `std::vector` (or `std::array`) rather than plain C-style arrays.

Comment: `iota` does not help; it's not an initializer. I can indeed use `std::array`. I cannot use `std::vector`.

Comment: Are you going to be modifying this array later on?  If not, then a `std::index_sequenex` could be what you want.  It is a compile time pack of `[0, N)`

Comment: Don't use C-style arrays in modern C++ - please.

Comment: code "like this" has a syntax error, did you forget some `{}` ?

Comment: @tenfour Can you also add the definition of `MyObject` to make the question more complete?

Comment: Unless the array is constant, use a loop.  Without the array being const, the compiler will probably generate a loop to copy the literals anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is impossible to intialize a built-in array like this. Arrays can only be default-initialized, value-initialized or aggregate-initialized (with exception for string literals). The only one of these allowing to specify different values for the elements is aggregate initialization and that requires explicitly listing each element.

(There is one other exception specific to non-static array members of classes. They may be initialized by copy through implicitly defined constructors of the enclosing class. However that still doesn't allow writing an initializer like you want.)

So you have to use `std::iota` or a loop after the initialization.

---

If you use `std::array` instead of a built-in array, you can define it as

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto initialize_array_with_indices() {
    return []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return std::array<T, N>{Is...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

To be used like

```
auto mObjects = initialize_array_with_indices<MyObject, ELEMENT_COUNT>();
```

The implementation above requires C++20. It can be written (slightly longer) for previous versions as well. Specifically before C++20 lambdas can't have explicit template parameters, so a helper function must be used instead (or a `constexpr` array of indices can be filled first with the approach below and then `std::apply` used on it to get the indices as a pack into the lambda). Also before C++17 it will require copy/move-constructibility of `T`.

An implementation that assumes that default-initialization of `MyObject` is possible and not undesirable would be much more straight-forward. (It would simply default-initialize a `std::array` and then loop through it to set the indices or use `std::iota` on it.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing this with both C++11 as well as C++20. Note that starting with C++17 we can do all this at **compile time**(if required). Additionally, I've made the converting constructor `constexpr`.

##### C++11 Version

This uses [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
struct C 
{
    int i;
    //added constexpr here
    constexpr C(int pi): i(pi)
    {

    }
};
/*
   Version #1         :     Used to end the recursion. 
   @tparam: destType  :     represents type of elements in the array to which we want to convert to. This parameter must be explicitly passed in angle brackets
   @tparam: sourceType:     represents type of elements in the array from which we want to convert. This parameter will be deduced using argument deduction
   @tparam: sourceSize:     represents size of the source array. This will also be deduced using deduction
   @tparam: extractedTypes  represents type of the values extracted by indexing and casting individual elments of sourceArray
   @return:                 this function template returns an std::array with elements of type destType and size sourceSize
*/
template<typename destType, typename sourceType, std::size_t sourceSize, typename... extractedTypes>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(extractedTypes) == sourceSize, std::array<destType, sourceSize> >::type 
cast_array(const std::array<sourceType, sourceSize> &sourceArray, const extractedTypes... extractedValues)
{
    return std::array<destType, sourceSize>{{extractedValues...}};//use pack expansion
}
/*
   Version 2          :     Recursively called until sizeof...(Types) becomes same as sourceSize 
   @tparam: destType  :     represents type to be converted to which must be explicitly passed in angle brackets
   @tparam: sourceType:     represents type of elements in the array from which we want to convert. This will be deduced using argument deduction
   @tparam: sourceSize:     represents size of the source array. This will also be deduced using deduction
   @tparam: extractedTypes  represents type of the values extracted by indexing and casting individual elments of sourceArray
   @return:                 this function template returns an std::array with elements of type destType and size sourceSize
*/
template<typename destType, typename sourceType, std::size_t sourceSize, typename... extractedTypes>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(extractedTypes) != sourceSize, std::array<destType, sourceSize> >::type
cast_array(const std::array<sourceType, sourceSize> &sourceArray, const extractedTypes... extractedValues)

{
    //recursively call cast_array passing the sourceArray and extracted elements until all elements are extracted
    return cast_array<destType>(sourceArray, extractedValues..., static_cast<destType>(sourceArray[sizeof...(extractedValues)]));
}//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^->extract/pass elements index by index by casting them to destType

static constexpr size_t ELEMENT_COUNT = 8;

template<std::size_t N = ELEMENT_COUNT>
std::array<C, N> make_array() 
{
    std::array<int, ELEMENT_COUNT> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(auto &elem: tempArray)
    {
        elem = ++count;
    }
    return cast_array<C>(tempArray);
}
int main()
{
    
    std::array<C, ELEMENT_COUNT> myArray = make_array();
    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: myArray)
    {
        std::cout << elem.i << std::endl;;
    }
    
}
```

[Working demo C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/YnaWEs9ex)

---

##### C++17 Version

With C++17, `std::array<T, N>::begin` is `constexpr`, so we can do all this at **compile time**(if needed). Here no changes have been made to the `cast_array` function template. Instead `constexpr` is added to `make_array` and `myArray`. So to avoid pasting the same code again and again, in the below code snippet I've only pasted the modified portion of the code. You can check out the full working example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4jnKKPWe3).

```
//--------------------------------------vvvvvvvvv------->added constexpr here
template<std::size_t N = ELEMENT_COUNT> constexpr std::array<C, N> make_array() 
{
    std::array<int, ELEMENT_COUNT> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(auto &elem: tempArray)
    {
        elem = ++count;
    }
    return cast_array<C>(tempArray);
}
int main()
{
    //note the constexpr here from C++17
    constexpr std::array<C, ELEMENT_COUNT> myArray = make_array();
    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: myArray)
    {
        std::cout << elem.i << std::endl;;
    }
    
}
```

[C++17 demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GfhEKGGjo)

---

##### C++20 Version

Here we make use of [requires](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/requires). Since changes have been done to `cast_array` also so I will post the whole code here again(except the documentation part)

```
struct C 
{
    int i;
    //added this constexpr
    constexpr C(int pi): i(pi)
    {

    }
};

template<typename destType, typename sourceType, std::size_t sourceSize, typename... extractedTypes>
constexpr std::array<destType, sourceSize> cast_array(const std::array<sourceType, sourceSize> &sourceArray, const extractedTypes... extractedValues)
requires (sizeof...(extractedTypes) == sourceSize) 
{
    return std::array<destType, sourceSize>{{extractedValues...}};//use pack expansion
}

template<typename destType, typename sourceType, std::size_t sourceSize, typename... extractedTypes>
constexpr std::array<destType, sourceSize> cast_array(const std::array<sourceType, sourceSize> &sourceArray, const extractedTypes... extractedValues)
requires (sizeof...(extractedTypes) != sourceSize)
{
    //recursively call cast_array passing the sourceArray and extracted elements until all elements are extracted
    return cast_array<destType>(sourceArray, extractedValues..., static_cast<destType>(sourceArray[sizeof...(extractedValues)]));
}//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^->extract/pass elements index by index by casting them to destType

static constexpr size_t ELEMENT_COUNT = 8;
//--------------------------------------vvvvvvvvv------->added constexpr here
template<std::size_t N = ELEMENT_COUNT> constexpr std::array<C, N> make_array() 
{
    std::array<int, ELEMENT_COUNT> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(auto &elem: tempArray)
    {
        elem = ++count;
    }
    return cast_array<C>(tempArray);
}
int main()
{
    
    constexpr std::array<C, ELEMENT_COUNT> myArray = make_array();

    
    for(const auto &elem: myArray)
    {
        std::cout << elem.i << std::endl;;
    }

}
```

[Working demo C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/zrbh9E3bf)

---

##### Note

If this is a one time thing then you can also use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of a separate function template `make_array`. See [demo with lambda](https://godbolt.org/z/zrbh9E3bf)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @user17732522 is fantastic and works in C++20. As they state, it only works for >=C++20, but with adaptations it can work for C++17 and earlier.

Here is a C++17 version, using a helper function:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
std::array<T, N> initialize_array_with_indices_helper(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array<T, N>{Is...};
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<T,N> initialize_array_with_indices() {
    return initialize_array_with_indices_helper<T, N>(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```